# How to make CQ5 use .htm extensions instead of .html?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am converting a huge site from MS CMS 2002 to Adobe CQ5. In the existing CMS all pages are referenced with .htm extension. When I create a new page in CQ5 it always has .html extension. Is there any way to force CQ5 to use .htm extension for pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of default extensions rendering the content can be modified in the configuration of an OSGi service called `SlingServletResolver`. In order to change it, open the following path:

```
/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.SlingServletResolver
```

on your CQ installation and add `htm` to the last option (*Default Extensions*). You may also use [`sling:OsgiConfig` nodes](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#OSGi%20Configuration%20in%20the%20Repository) to have the service configured automatically.

Comment: This solution worked really well for me. Just adding "htm" to the list of default extensions at the SlingServletResolver made CQ5 retrieve the files regardless of whether  .html or .htm extension is used in the request URL. No redirect or file rename is necessary!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers a different approach is to create an internal redirect from your htm to the new html pages.  You can create a Sling mapping under /etc/map which will redirect htm requests to html.

Information on configuring the sling mapping can be found here http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html under Root Level Mappings -> Mapping Entry Specification

Answer (score 1):

Tomek has provided the best solution for this problem.  However, this solution will change the extension type for all the pages.  If you want another solution to target specific pages then here is the solution:

Override the head.jsp for /libs/foundation/components/page by copying this file to apps folder and there specify the content-type and content="text/htm.
 Now you have to refer to this component as a superResoucetype for every component or template wherever you want a htm or any other extension extension.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @vonPetrushev I didn't have enough reputation point(i.e. 50 points) to comment on others ,So i added this answer.